# Naigation Drawer doesn't do any action after clicking on a second item

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I created a drawer navigation with some items , the problem is when i click on the first item it works fine, even for the second item for first time it works , but if i click on "Presentation" and then go to "Atout et réalisaion" all items are blocked and i can see only "Presentation" fragment, the same from "Atout et réalisaion" to "Presentation".

How can i fix that ? here is my MainActivity Class, thanks.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener ,FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                displayView(R.id.nav_presentation);




            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void displayView(int viewId) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

        switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.nav_presentation:
                fragment = new FragmentPresentation();
                title  = "Presentation";
                break;

           case R.id.nav_aerealisation:
             fragment = new AERealisationFragment();
                title = "Atout et Réalisation";
                break;

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        // set the toolbar title
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        displayView(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: try remove this `DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` from `displayView(int viewId)`

Comment: it doesn't work , and it becomes so slow